# jqGrid get default entry from server side

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using a jqgrid with MVC. Here is my markup:

```js
$("#list").jqGrid({
    url: '/GstRate/GstRateGridData/',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames: ['GstRateLookupId', 'Percentage Rate', 'Start Date', 'End Date', 'CreatedByUserName', 'CreatedDateTime', ''],
    colModel: [
          { name: 'GstRateLookupId', index: 'GstRateLookupId', hidden: true, key: true, editable: true, editrules: { required: false }, editoptions: { defaultValue: '0'} },
          { name: 'PercentageRate', index: 'PercentageRate', editable: true, editrules: { required: true} },
          { name: 'StartDate', index: 'StartDate', width: 400, align: 'center', formatter: 'date', editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, formatoptions: { srcformat: 'd/m/y', newformat: 'd-m-y' }, editoptions: { dataInit: function (element) { $(element).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'd-m-y' }) } } },
          { name: 'EndDate', index: 'EndDate', width: 400, align: 'center', editable: true, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'd/m/y', newformat: 'd-m-y' }, editoptions: { dataInit: function (element) { $(element).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'd-m-y' }) } } },
          { name: 'CreatedByUserName', index: 'CreatedByUserName', hidden: true, editable: true, editrules: { required: false} },
          { name: 'CreatedDateTime', index: 'CreatedDateTime', hidden: true, editable: true, editrules: { required: false} },
          { name: 'act', index: 'act', width: 55, align: 'center', sortable: false, formatter: 'actions', formatoptions: { keys: true, delbutton: false} }
          ],
    pager: $('#pager'),
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
    viewrecords: true,
    imgpath: '',
    caption: 'Gst Rates',
    editurl: '/GstRate/SaveGstRate/'
});
$("#list").navGrid('#pager', { edit: false, add: true, del: true, search: false }, {}, {}, { url: "/../GstRate/DeleteGstRate" });
```

This is working fine but I want to enhance it so that when a new entry is added the startdate value is readonly and defaults to the end date value of the last entry in the database.

The only way I can think of doing this is by somehow calling a server side method to populate the start date in the pop up create new dialog box.

I was thinking of using the dataUrl value in the editoptions to do this but this dataUrl only seems to work for when populating a select list. I don't want a select list here just a readonly text box.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two different solution ways:

1. You use [beforeShowForm](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events) callback set input field of 'StartDate' to readonly and then send request to the server manually per `$.ajax`. Inside of `success` callback of the requests you can set the data in the input field of 'StartDate' received from the server.
2. If you fill the grid you use `userdata` to save additional information in the grid. Inside of `dataInit` of the 'StartDate' you get the data which you need from internal `userData` parameter and make the initialization of the input field.